# MySQL Table name start with an underscore. Special meaning?

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a table name that starts with an underscore does that give any special status to the table?

I am asking because the table does not seem to be taken by the replication in some instances. In the MySQL Query Browser it is also impossible to use the "Edit" feature on that table but it is on all the other tables.

We are using MySQL 5.0.37

Cheers,

Comment: Are there any prefix to those tables?

Comment: No the table name is actually _tableversion it the only one in the schema

Comment: When you are using the table name in an SQL statement, be sure to call it with quotes e.g. `'_tablename'` - the underscore may complicate in the statements, but not in the SQL database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does nothing special ^^